# How to enable a disabled Button after filling Entry widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 `Entry`s and one button. I want to make that button's state disabled until the two `Entry`s are filled in. How can I achieve that?

```
howManyStocksLabel = Label(root, text = "How many stocks do you want to evaluate?")
howManyStocksLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
howManyStocksEntry = Entry(root, borderwidth = 3)
howManyStocksEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

riskLabel = Label(root, text = "Enter risk %")
riskLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
riskEntry = Entry(root, borderwidth = 3)
riskEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

nextButton = Button(root, text = "Next!", width = 20, height = 2,state = DISABLED,
                    fg = 'green', bg = 'white',
                    command= lambda: myClick(riskEntry, howManyStocksEntry, var))
nextButton.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

I tried to check whether the entries are filled in or not by:

```
if(riskEntry.get() != ""):
    ....................
```

but it just doesn't work.

Comment: For future reference: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the value is there after the user inputs it. Also, you can use `tk.StringVar()` as a text variable and trace it.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_entry(*args):
    if r1.get() and r2.get():
        b1.config(state='normal')
    else:
        b1.config(state='disabled')

root = tk.Tk()
r1 = tk.StringVar(master=root)
r2 = tk.StringVar(master=root)
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=r1)
e1.pack()
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=r2)
e2.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Click Me!', state='disabled')
b1.pack()

r1.trace('w', check_entry)
r2.trace('w', check_entry)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a binding on your entry widgets to check whether the user has entered anything into the entry or not.

This code will fire the check_entry function every time the user types in one of the entry boxes:

```
riskEntry.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_entry)
howManyStocksEntry.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_entry)
```

Then your check_entry function might look like this:

```
def check_entry(event):  #event is required for all functions that use a binding
    if riskEntry.get() and howManyStocksEntry.get():
        nextButton.config(state=NORMAL)
    else:
        nextButton.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: How should I call the `check_entry` function? And what do you mean by `event` as a parameter? I don't quite understand.

Comment: The purpose of bindings is to fire the function automatically, as soon as the binding event happens. In this case, the binding event is a "Key Release" which means the function will fire automatically every time the user types a key on their keyboard, so long as they are typing into the entry box. The "event" parameter just needs to be there, even if the "event" variable isn't used in the function itself, otherwise the function won't fire. So in short, you do not "need" to call the function - it will be called when the binding event happens.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to utilize the ability to "validate" their contents that `Entry` widgets support — see [adding validation to an Entry widget](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html) — but make it check the contents of *multiple* `Entry` widgets and change the state of a `Button` accordingly.

Below shows how to do this via a helper `class` that encapsulates most of the messy details needed to make doing it relatively painless. Any number of `Entry` widgets can be "watched", so it scales well to handle forms consisting of many more than merely two entries.

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *


class ButtonEnabler:
    """ Enable/disable a Button depending on whether all specified Entry widgets
        are non-empty (i.e. contain at least one character).
    """
    def __init__(self, button, *entries):
        self.button = button
        self.entries = entries

        for entry in self.entries:
            func = root.register(partial(self.check_entries, entry))
            entry.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(func, '%P'))

    def check_entries(self, this_entry, new_value):
        other_entries = (entry for entry in self.entries if entry is not this_entry)
        all_others_filled = all(entry.get() for entry in other_entries)
        combined = bool(new_value) and all_others_filled
        self.button.config(state=NORMAL if combined else DISABLED)
        return True


root = tk.Tk()

howManyStocksLabel = tk.Label(root, text="How many stocks do you want to evaluate?")
howManyStocksLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
howManyStocksEntry = tk.Entry(root, borderwidth=3)
howManyStocksEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

riskLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Enter risk %")
riskLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
riskEntry = tk.Entry(root, borderwidth=3)
riskEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)

nextButton = tk.Button(root, text="Next!", width=20, height=2, state=DISABLED,
                       fg='green', bg='white', disabledforeground='light grey',
                       command=lambda: myClick(riskEntry, howManyStocksEntry, var))
nextButton.grid(row=4, column=1)

enabler = ButtonEnabler(nextButton, howManyStocksEntry, riskEntry)
root.mainloop()
```